# Inverse function theorem and Implicit function theorem.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse, partial-derivative

I have been trying to prove that implicit function theorem implies the inverse function theorem. Be $F: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\det[DF(x_0)]\neq 0$ for $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Be $H: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined as follows:

$$H(x,y)= F(x)-y  \quad \forall (x,y) \in  \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n . $$

We can use the implicit function theorem to see that exist $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ an open set that has $(x_0 , F(x_0))$ as an element, $B\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ an open set that has $F(x_0)$ as an element, and a function $f : B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with:
 $$ A \cap \{ (x, y) : H(x,y)= 0 \}= \{ ( f(y), y) : y \in B \}. $$

It seems that $f$ is the inverse function of $F$, but I can't find a way to define the domain in which $F$ is bijective. Is there any tip?

Comment: Maybe see page 8 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.2066v1.pdf

Comment: Here is one awkward approach: After creating $f$, now look at $G(x,y) = f(y)-x$, and note that the formula for ${ \partial f(F(x_0)) \over \partial y}$ shows that $f$ is invertible. This gives you some $\phi$ defined on an open set $A$ such that $f(\phi(x)) = x$ for $x \in A$. Hence the range of $f$ includes some open set on which $F$ is bijective.

Comment: Hello @copper.hat Why is $F(A)$ open?

Comment: @ViniciusRodrigues: Note that $F(f(\phi(x))) = F(x) =\phi(x)$ for $x \in A$, and since $\phi$ is a homeomorphism, $\phi(A)$ is open. Since $\phi=F$ on $A$ we see that $F(A)$ is open (the $A$ here is the $A$ in my comment, not the $A$ in the question, unfortunate choice of symbol, in retrospect!).